# Декоратор воркера и мультипроцессинг на python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

upd.
Всем привет. Данный декоратор должен выполнять некую функцию, пока выполняется декодируемая функция.
Однако, есть проблемный случай.Проблема возникает со значения int_range >= 13150 в декодируемой функции. Если результат меньше, либо снять декоратор, то все отрабатывает корректно

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, pinger_func, pinger_step: int):
        self.pinger_func = pinger_func
        self.pinger_step = pinger_step

    def __call__(self, func):
        q = Queue()
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            def subprocess():
                q.put(func(*args, **kwargs))
            p = Process(target=subprocess)
            p.start()
            while p.is_alive():
                self.pinger_func(self.pinger_step)
            else:
                p.close()
                return q.get()
        return wrapper 
    
    
def sender(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    print("i'm pinger")


@Decorator(sender, 1)
def test(int_range):
    time.sleep(5)
    print('pre done')
    rst = [(i,) for i in range(int_range)] ### эмуляция данных
    print('done')
    return rst
  

print(test(15000))
```

Тестирую на python 3.10.5. При int_range 15000 работает некорректно:
[image: problem]

При 13149, либо снятом декораторе, все - ок.
[image: ok]

Comment: Мне кажется проблема в отсутствии `p.join()`, без него `is_alive()` так и будет возвращать `True`, если я правильно понял этот вопрос-ответ, хотя может тут и про другое https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353677/multiprocessing-process-is-alive-returns-true-although-process-has-finished-w

Comment: @CrazyElf `>>> p = multiprocessing.Process(target=time.sleep, args=[1])
>>> p.is_alive()
False
` всё норм с is_alive

Comment: Дополнил вопрос. Нет, joint не поможет.

Comment: Хм... По идее, все же обрабатывается в одном процессе, а в другом работает пингалка. Или, очереди пораждают свои процессы? Без декоратора вообще все работает корректно.

Comment: Кстати, вот это почитайте https://pythonspeed.com/articles/python-multiprocessing/

Comment: Спасибо. Попробовал использовать Pipe, стал прожевывать больше 16000, но все равно, мало. У меня в задании несколько сотен тысяч значений. При 100000 он так же сыпется. C get_context без изменений

Comment: Хм, у меня с `get_context` вообще ругаться начало, что `pickle` не проходит )  Кстати, проверку `if __main__ == '__main__`:` поставьте всё-таки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, с использованием отдельной очереди сообщений:

```
class Decorator:
    def __init__(self, pinger_func, pinger_step: int):
        self.pinger_func = pinger_func
        self.pinger_step = pinger_step

    def __call__(self, func):
        q = Queue()
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            def subprocess():
                q.put(func(*args, **kwargs))
            p = Process(target=subprocess)
            p.start()
            while p.is_alive():
                self.pinger_func(self.pinger_step)
            else:
                p.close()
                return q.get()
        return wrapper
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Самое забавное, только что сам допер до такого же решения, как у Вас, и хотел его добавить в комменты.

Comment: Однако, если декорировать функцию, которая так же создает процессы через Pool, возникает проблема. Вероятно, не выполняется условие while p.is_alive(). В процессах у меня вызываются треды, в каждом треде вызывается netmiko. Если все узлы в задании не получают данных, то все нормально. Если же данные получен, выход из while p.is_alive() не происходит. Даже нет идей, почему так.

Comment: @Nik без минимального воспроизводимого примера, невозможно найти ошибку...

Comment: Да, конечно. Удалось воспроизвести проблему. Дополнил свой вопрос.

Comment: Причем, дело не в процессах, а в объеме данных. Скорректировал ещё раз. Если снять декоратор, получим результат, а с декоратором происходит зацикливание.

Comment: Проблема возникает со значения range(13150). Все что меньше отрабатывает корректно.